How to scale out from the center of a cylinder?
With the bumpy cylinder, and with just the outside vertexes selected, I need to scale all the selected vertices to the same distance from the centre point.
I can acheive what I want and as an example on a flat object, by E X 0.5, S X 0. As you can see on the recatngular version all the forward facing vertex are at the same height. That is what I am trying to acheive from the centre of the cylinder.




Have you tried S + Shift-Z?

You need to scale all to the same distance from the center? So you mean you want to flatten the bumpiness on the outside?

I have added detail to the question, I dont think the S + Shift Z works here, unles I'm geting it wrong.

Set this to 3d cursor or to bounding box center


If you mean you want to smoothen the outside so that it is not bumpy anymore, perhaps there are better ways but I can't think of any apart from using the Shrinkwrap modifier.
First I select the outer vertices and assign them to a Vertex Group with a Weight of 1.

Then I create a second cylinder slightly larger than the bumpy one. I've set it in the Object Properties to Viewport Display > Display As > Wire so you can see the other inside. I've given it some resolution for a better result.

The bumpy cylinder now gets a Shrinkwrap modifier. I leave it to the default settings, select the new cylinder as Target and the Vertex Group "Group" so that it only affects the selected vertices. Here I made the outer cylinder invisible to show the result:

Now this is a very harsh transition because in the vertex group the vertices have a weight of either 1 (fully affected) or 0 (not affected). By assigning gradually lower weights to the outer vertices manually or with weight painting etc. you can get a smoother transition.


I dont think this will acheive what I need, I have added detail to the question
